# Visual styles in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, themes, aero-glass, visual-styles

I have the following C++ code (native desktop app) that uses Microsoft's [Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to draw a close button.

```
RECT r = DetermineButtonRect();
HANDLE h = OpenThemeData(Handle, L"WINDOW");
DrawThemeBackground(h, hdc, WP_CLOSEBUTTON, CBS_NORMAL, &rect, NULL);
CloseThemeData(h);
```

This works fine in earlier versions of Windows, but in Windows 8, it insists on drawing in the Windows 7 style.  This isn't horrible, but it's still frustrating to not have all of the parts of the application use the same visual style.  Here's a screenshot of what this looks like:

[image: close buttons]

From top to bottom:

- The standard Windows 8 close button, using Windows 8's minimalist non-Glass appearance.
- The standard Windows 8 MDI close button (WP_MDICLOSEBUTTON, looking a bit out of place due to its more pronounced gradient, but that's Microsoft's decision.
- The close button that I'm drawing myself, using a full-blown Aero Glass style (identical appearance to Windows 7) and looking rather out of place as a result.

Is there any way to get the Visual Styles API to draw Windows 8 style (non-Glass) buttons?  Or is there a different API I should be using?

Comment: It is a Great Unanswered Question.  Dabbled at this before, spent a ridiculous amount of time on it today that I shouldn't have.  Nothing, nada, zippo.  I'm now 98% sure that this can't be done.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks for taking the time to research this.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WP_SMALLCLOSEBUTTON` which appears to work on both Windows 7 and Windows 8 with the correct theme.

Comment: This isn't the case for Windows 10 unfortunately.